# Angular: how to make a configurable filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Is it possible to create a configurable filter the way you can create configurable services:

```
angular.module('app', [])
       .provider('resourceUrl', function($filterProvider) { 

    var base = '/';

    this.setPrefix = function(prefix) {base = prefix};

    $filterProvider.register('resourceUrl', resourceUrlFilter);

    this.$get = ??

    function resourceUrlFilter(url) { /* returns the new url */ }
})
```

I wan't to create a filter that adds a base url prefix to a path string and the url prefix should be configurable.

Currently I achieve this by injecting a constant in the filter

```
angular.module('app', [])
       .constant('baseUrl', '...')
       .filter('resourceUrl', ['baseUrl', function(baseUrl) {

       return function resourceUrlFilter(url) { /* returns the new url */ }
}]
```

Comment: Did you find your answer ?

Comment: I think it's not possible to create configurable filter the way configurable services are defined. I guess I used the `inject constant` solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a reminder of this question today, and recently I had to use some filters in a service, and this crossed my mind:

> Since to inject a filter into a service let's say I have created the `customDate` filter, I have to provide the name `customDateFilter` in order to inject it

```
 myModule.factory('MyData', function(customDateFilter) { /* code */ });
```

So I thought:

> Maybe I can register a filter the same way I register a service but then append `Filter` to the name, **and it worked**.

I don't know if it is considered legal to register a filter in this way, or whether it won't be dropped in the future
but this is a way that allows you to register a filter with a provider

---

#### The short version:

You can register a configurable filter, by creating a `ServiceProvider` the way usual configurable services are created -> https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe
But when you register the `ServiceProvider` append `Filter` to the service name:

JS

```
var module = angular.module('app', [])
var customDate = function filterProvider() { /* ServiceProvider definition */ };
myModule.provider('customDateFilter', customDate);
```

HTML

```
<p>Some date: <span>{{ $ctrl.date | customDate }}</span> </p>
```

---

#### Working plunk example

This plunk shows an example of a baseUrl filter that can be configured with
a prefix in a module's `config` block
https://plnkr.co/edit/RkTkKM?p=preview

---

#### Other Options

You can always create a service that performs the filtering and then expose it through a filter by injecting it to the `filter` factory. And this service can be a configurable service using the `Provider Recipe`

```
class FilteringServiceProvider {

    $get() { return new FilteringService(this.configuration) }

    configure(params) { /* some config logic */ }
}

class FilteringService {

  constructor(configuration) {}

  filterDate(date) { /* some filtering on the date and return a value */ }
}

const myModule = angular.module('app.filters', []);

myModule
  .provider('filteringService', FilteringServiceProvider)
  .filter('customDate', (filteringService) => filteringService.filterDate);
```